# How do I execute multiple animations linearly in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have three animations (translate) that I want to execute linearly.  Animation 1 starts, Animation 2 starts when Animation 1 ends, and Animation 3 starts when Animation 2 ends.

So far the only thing I am able to do is up to two animation with a AnimationEnd method which executes Animation 2.

How would I be able to up to X animation linearly?

Also the animation set seems to execute animations at the same time so that is no help for me.

Comment: Use an AnimationSet -- for an example see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6267645/115676

Answer (score 1):

Use animation's [android:startOffset](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#attr_android%3astartOffset) attribute.

Comment: I tried putting 3 animations in an animation set with offset time after each other but doesn't work.  Can you provide an example please.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an AnimationSet and set the appropriate startOffsets:

```
AnimationSet animations = new AnimationSet(false);

Animation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(...);
scaleAnimation.setDuration(500);
animations.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);

Animation translateAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(...);
translateAnimation.setStartOffset(500);
translateAnimation.setDuration(500);
animations.addAnimation(translateAnimation);

myView.startAnimation(animations);
```