# Chained rotate animation not functioning

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm attempting to use rotate to give a view the semblance of shaking side to side. I've attempted to define the animation programmatically  and am using animationset to loop it as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267473/how-to-chain-animation-in-android-to-the-same-view). However on execute the code doesn't seem to be doing anything at all.

```
AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

RotateAnimation rotright = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 20.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.9f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotright.setDuration(0);
set.addAnimation(rotright);

RotateAnimation rotleft = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 340.0f,
        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.9f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rotleft.setDuration(0);
set.addAnimation(rotleft);

blender.startAnimation( set );
}
};
```

Any clues as to how exactly I've messed up would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rotright.setDuration(0);

rotleft.setDuration(0);
```

You've set the duration of the two animations to `0`, effectively creating *instant* rotations, which results in no animation at all. Try setting some values greater than zero - remember you're setting milliseconds.

Comment: Much appreciated. If I might extend my question, it isn't looping still. Any idea why?

Comment: @user1398478: Have you set [`setRepeatMode(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html#setRepeatMode%28int%29) on your `AnimationSet`? I don't see it in your original code snippet. You can pass in either `Animation.RESTART` or `Animation.REVERSE`, depending on the desired effect.